# How can I create a weather-proof pass-through connection between an outside vacuum and an inside hose?

Tags: vacuum

I want to mount a fireplace vacuum on the outside of an exterior wall. I need some sort of pass-through device that would allow for connecting the vacuum hose on the exterior and the interior, but I also need some form of a hinged mechanism to keep out bugs and weather -- basically some form of insulation. Anyone know a good method to accomplish this type of application?

Thank you in advance for any info.

Comment: perhaps a central vacuum port -   https://www.centralvacuumstores.com/central-vacuum/installation-kits-and-components/pre-packaged-inlet-kits/13831

Comment: I fixed your title and removed your product recommendation request.  Product recommendations and shopping questions are off topic here.

Comment: What vacuum are you using that tolerates weather exposure?

Comment: I revised your question and tags to remove most of the fireplace stuff, which isn't really relevant. Your question is about vacuum connections only.

Comment: Central vac ports aren't weatherproof, and they're proprietary. You'd have to install them back-to-back and provide weatherproofing some other way *if* you're lucky enough to find one that fits your hose.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A side note: if you accidentally vacuum up an ember, things get bad fast. It seems it would be even worse if you were using the vacuum remotely, so it'd burn merrily for a while before you noticed.